# 'db2app64.dll' is missing in docker container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, docker-compose, db2

I'm using docker desktop (windows containers) to run my application which is supposed to send request to remote server with ibm database. locally everything works fine and there is 'db2app64.dll' file in bin\debug\net6.0\clidriver\bin. But in container whenever code reaches part where it sends request to database I get this error in logs of container: System.DllNotFoundException:
Unable to load DLL 'db2app64.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)

My dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
USER ContainerAdministrator
RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\app\bin\Debug\net6.0\clidriver\bin;C:\app\bin\Debug\net6.0\clidriver\;C:\app\bin\Debug\net6.0\clidriver\lib"
USER ContainerUser
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["nuget.config", "."]
COPY ["MyApp/MyApp.csproj", "MyApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyApp/MyApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyApp"
RUN dotnet build "MyApp.csproj" -c %BUILD_CONFIGURATION% -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION
RUN dotnet publish "MyApp.csproj" -c %BUILD_CONFIGURATION% -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

Comment: @viveknuna No, I'm already using windows package version. And I also have visited all possible pages with answers to similar questions.

Comment: Your Dockerfile mentions clidriver in a specific location, but what installs that component there?  If you shell into the container, is that location present?

Comment: @mao Yes, that file is present in the container. https://ibb.co/7S1499W